# Recover file deleted using git mergetool

Tags: git

I had git merge conflicts after deleting some files (on OSX) and ran:

```
git mergetool
```

After running through most of the conflicts, I accidentally deleted a local file I meant to keep:

```
Deleted merge conflict for 'app/xxxapp/xxxapp/AppDelegate.swift':
  {local}: created file
  {remote}: deleted
Use (c)reated or (d)eleted file, or (a)bort? d
```

Is there any way to recover the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: after `git mergetool` finishes (or in another window), run:

```
git checkout --ours app/xxxapp/xxxapp/AppDelegate.swift
git add app/xxxapp/xxxapp/AppDelegate.swift
```

The first command extracts the HEAD version of the file into the work-tree, and the second tells Git that this is the correct resolution (vs what you already told Git through `git mergetool`: that the correct resolution was to discard the file).

You can also or instead use:

```
git checkout HEAD app/xxxapp/xxxapp/AppDelegate.swift
```

The latter has the advantage of marking the item resolved all in one command.